# Stabilizers Of The H Code

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

How does one interpret the ... in the third and fourth stabilizers of the [H code](https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/quantum_h)? Is this $[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, \dots]$ or $[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8,\dots]$? Can someone please write this out for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$? Thanks.

Comment: [1,2,,5,6,9,10] would skip over qubits 7,8 so I'm sure it's not right. Going with [1,2,5,6,7,8],[1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] is consistent with the definitions in the original paper : $S_1=X_1X_2X_3X_4$,$S_3=X_1X_2X_5X_6\cdots X_n$,$\bar X_i=X_1X_3 X_{i+4}$.

Comment: I was leaning that direction as well, but these have parameters $$[[k + 4, k, 2]]$, so if $k = 1$, $n = 5$. But then $S_3$ and $S_4$ have odd overlap and don't commute.

Comment: original paper defines these as $[[n,n-4,2]]$ codes for *even*  $n \geq 6$

Comment: Oh! I missed that line completely somehow. That clears up everything, thanks. You should make an answer out of this so I can mark it answered.